# Django - Accessing a boolean field of a model in html

Tags: django

My profile model has a `BooleanField` called `teacher_status`, and I want to give users with the `teacher_status` as True extra features within the website, and I am having trouble accessing the field.

Profile model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    RANKS = [(f'{i}D', f'{i}K') for i in range(1,19)]
    for i in range(1, 10):
        RANKS.append((f'{i}D', f'{i}D'))
        
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=225, blank=True, default='')
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=3, default='18K', choices=RANKS)
    teacher_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.user.username}'s Profile"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            img.thumbnail((300,300))
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

This is what I did in the html:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if user.profile.teacher_status == true %}
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'post-create' %}">Create Post</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Django template needs a python-style True/False that is capitalised, but in your template you can just do `{% if user.profile.teacher_status %}`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean is...

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% if user.profile.teacher_status %} # modify here...
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'post-create' %}">Create Post</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```